# Unit test for a click on <a>

Tags: html, angular, jestjs

I have this.

```
<a class="projects-results__items" (click)="selectProject(project)">
   <p class="projects-results__items--name project-name" appIsEllipsisActive>{{project.name}}</p>
   <em class="ki-key-right"></em>
</a>
```

I want to unit test the click event. So i wrote something like this.

```
test('should select project', async () => { 
    component.projectSelectedId = navigationV2Data[0].id;
    const selectProjectLink = nativeElement.querySelector('a.projects-results__items') as HTMLLinkElement;
    selectProjectLink.click();
    tick();
    console.log(selectProjectLink);
```

})

Obviously there is no expectation yet. The problem is that i get an error on the test and is this:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')**

I cant' figure out what is exactly the problem in my test. I mean, it can't find a reference to the , and i don't know why. Maybe you can. Thanks

Comment: An `a` should not have a click event handler - the click should be going wherever the `href` takes you. Semantically, what you have there is a _button_.

Comment: ok, but with the code as i wrote, should at list bring something? lets say if i console.log selectProjectLink, i should see something instead of null

Comment: How is nativeElement defined?